# List of all two and three letter syllables in Koine Greek required

Tags: greek

I'd like to get a list of all possible  two and three letter syllables in Koine Greek. Reference I have used is:

https://www.sttmedia.com/syllablefrequency-greek

but I'm afraid it doesn't contain those which contain double consonants and long vowels, plus I don't know if it is totally valid for ancient Koine Greek. For example, I don't see omega Ω used in the above syllable list.

Shouldn't Omega be regarded as a full complete syllable, even it is a single letter, it quantifies as two?

Thus I also suspect, that there are similar three letter syllables, that indeed are constructed by a consonant and omega. Maybe there are similar consonants, that looks like single letter but are quantified as two?

Comment: Please be aware that this is a website about learning and teaching languages, and that your question does not look relevant to either learning or teaching Greek. Could you clarify whether this is just a question about features of Koine Greek (off topic on this site) or how it is relevant to learning or teaching Koine Greek?

Comment: I see. I quess only in sense of learning Greek alphabet and syllables in terms of learning word and phrase construction is loosely related then. Could you point me any site in SE that would better fit for the question?

Comment: You can support the [site proposal for Greek](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101509/greek-language) if you haven't done that yet (but you can't post questions there until it has enough supporters to move into the beta phase). For the moment, you can try Latin SE, which already has a number of questions about [Greek](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek).